# Redirect to another page on submit

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage, cloud

Hello all I have the below code where it upserts into a DE.  I also want to redirect to a new cloud page on clicking submit.  The issue is I did find a way to do it by using  action="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(@optoutRedirect,'id', @id))=%%"

But then it does not upsert into a DE so I lose that functionality.  Anyway to make it INSERT into a DE AND also redirect to a new website or cloudpage?

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

if (Request.Method == "POST") {
  /*var subscriberKey = Request.FormParameter(_susbcriberKey);*/
  var subscriberKey = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("sfmc_key");
  /*var reason = Request.FormParameter("reason");*/
 var reason = Request.GetFormField("reason");
  
  var deName = "Unsubformsubmit_xxxx"; /* Replace with the name of your data extension */
  
  var deRows = Platform.Function.InsertDE(deName, ["SubscriberKey", "reason"], [subscriberKey, reason]);
  
  
  if (deRows > 0) {
    // Success
    Platform.Response.Write("Form submitted successfully.");
  } else {
    // Error
    Platform.Response.Write("Error submitting form.");
  }
}
</script> 

  <form method="post"> 
            <select name="reason" id="selectBox" onchange="testfunc();">
            <option >1</option>
            <option >2</option>
            <option >3</option>
            <option >4</option>
            <option >5</option>
          </select> <br>
            <textarea  style="display:none;" class="text-field" id="textField" name="reason"></textarea> <br>
          <button onclick="document.forms[0].submit()" type="submit" class="button">Submit</button> 
        </form>
```

Comment: why don't you just give the URL like `<form action=<yourURL>`

Comment: Did you figure out a way to do this? I'm attempting to build the same functionality

Answer (score 0):

InsertDE is for emails. *InsertDATA* is what you want on cloudpages.

See here (green boxes):
https://ampscript.guide/insertdata/

vs here:
https://ampscript.guide/insertde/

In general, this should work. An insert / upsert on a cloudpage does not prevent the redirect. Definitely try exchanging that function first.